# Data Exploration with Python with formatted output

Tags: python, matplotlib, browser, statistics

I am using the loans data from lendingclub to perform some EDA:

[image]

I have generated the descriptive stats:

```
#Get the descriptive stats
desc=loans.describe(include='all')
desc.style.set_properties(subset=cols, **{'width' :'850px'})
#Transpose the ouput
df1_transposed = desc.T
```

The transpose is done in order to have the stats as columns & fields as rows. I wish to generate something like the following:

[image]

My doubts are :
1.How will it be possible to have the frequency plots beside each of the fields ?
2.How can the results be viewed in the browser?
3.Also is it possible to generate multiple tabs as a part of the same output using Python?

Would be great if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [Dash by plotly](https://dash.plot.ly/gallery).

Dash is easy to get started with and they have great documentation for nearly any kind of graph / chart you wish to create.  Using Dash you can create simple yet elegant graphs and charts from Python that will likely satisfy your requirements:

1. frequency plots next to your fields (should be no problem)
2. viewing results in the browser (this is standard behavior of all Dash apps)
3. multiple tabs (see the Vanguard Report example app from the link above)

***Note:*** I'm **not** affiliated with Dash or Plotly in any way.  I just like the product and have had a good experience going through their tutorials and creating beautiful and functional charts with minimal effort.